# Gradle build error with branch io and crashlytics

Tags: android-studio, gradle, crashlytics

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'app_name'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
 > Could not find com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers-shim:0.0.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/answers-shim/0.0.3/answers-shim-0.0.3.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/answers-shim/0.0.3/answers-shim-0.0.3.aar
         file:/Users/arun/repos/app_name/libs/answers-shim-0.0.3.aar
file:/Users/arun/repos/app_name/libs/answers-shim.aar
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/answers-shim/0.0.3/answers-shim-0.0.3.pom
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/answers-shim/0.0.3/answers-shim-0.0.3.aar
         file:/Users/arun/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/answers-shim/0.0.3/answers-shim-0.0.3.pom
         file:/Users/arun/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/answers-shim/0.0.3/answers-shim-0.0.3.aar
         file:/Users/arun/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/answers-shim/0.0.3/answers-shim-0.0.3.pom
         file:/Users/arun/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/answers-shim/0.0.3/answers-shim-0.0.3.aar
     Required by:
         :app_name:unspecified > io.branch.sdk.android:library:1.14.2
```

branch-io originally was `io.branch.sdk.android:library:1+` I then tried

`io.branch.sdk.android:library:1.14.1` and `io.branch.sdk.android:library:1.14.2` with the same error.

Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

`com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers-shim:0.0.3` isn't available on mavenCentral. Add jcenter to your repository section.

ref: https://bintray.com/fabric/fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android%3Aanswers-shim/view

Example:

```
repositories {
  jcenter()
}
```

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: @Sam see Example 1 here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't plan to use the Fabric Answers integration, and don't want to import the `answers-shim`, just import your project as follows:

replace `io.branch.sdk.android:library:1.14.1` with

```
implementation ('io.branch.sdk.android:library:3.+') {
    exclude module: 'answers-shim'
}
```

Source - https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking