# Failed to resolve: com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers-shim:0.0.3

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics

I have updated the android Studio to the latest version since I started getting gradle sync issues:

> Failed to resolve: com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers-shim:0.0.3

How can I resolve it?

This is the content of the gradle I have

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {


        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath true
                applicationId "com.XXXXX.YYYYYY"
                minSdkVersion 21
                targetSdkVersion 26
                multiDexEnabled true
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable "ResourceType"
    }

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/icu4j-4_4_2_2.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.6.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile files('libs/zip4j_1.2.6.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.14.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.38.1'

    // Google
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:16.0.7'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
    compile project(':pdflibrary')

    //implementation
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'   
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Kindly find below the project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.9'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
    }
}
```

PDF Library build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
//apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'



    defaultConfig {


        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath true
                minSdkVersion 21
                targetSdkVersion 26
                versionCode 1
                versionName '1'
            }
        }
   }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

publish {
    userOrg = 'thefinestartist'
    groupId = 'com.thefinestartist'
    artifactId = 'finestwebview'
    publishVersion = '1'
    desc = 'Beautiful and customizable Android Activity that shows web pages within an app.'
    website = 'https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/FinestWebView-Android'
}
```

Comment: Do you have `jcenter()` in `repositories` block in project-wide `build.gradle`?

Comment: Yes I do as shown in the code above.

Comment: This is your module-wide `build.gradle`, not the **project-wide** `build.gradle`. However I am not sure if this is the cause of problem.

Comment: I have updated the answer and included the project build.gradle

Comment: Due to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974511/gradle-build-error-with-branch-io-and-crashlytics, you may need to have a look at the **Required by:** section, and found the corresponing update version of that library. (Maybe inside the module `pdflibrary`)?

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, I have added the repository to pdf library build.gradle, but unfortunately still facing the same issue. I have re-updated the question to include the pdf library build.gradle.

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Theoretically, this is the correct solution. However, you can't see _that_ dependency in this question. Neither the `crashlytics`, nor anything it depends (I tried to search that before comment). So maybe that "Required By" field is important.

Comment: `com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers-shim:0.0.3` is a transitive dependency of `com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.14.1@aar` (in your app level build). Please try to upgrade the version of this module, if you need to use it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I git rid of the error, kindly right it as answer so I may accept it and give the bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really an aswer but a tip to solve this kind or error: generally when you have some dependency resolution issues, you need to understand from where is this dependency coming from, using the Gradle `dependencies` task :

```
./gradlew dependencies 

Executing tasks: [dependencies]

[ ... ]

compile - Compile dependencies for 'main' sources (deprecated: use 'implementation' instead).
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3
+--- com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.14.1
|    +--- com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:1.11.1
|    |    +--- com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.7.0
|    |    |    +--- com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.8.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3 -> 2.4
|    |    |    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.12
|    |    |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4
|    |    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.12
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 -> 27.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2
{ ... }               
|    |    \--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
|    +--- com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.7.0 (*)
|    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.12
|    +--- com.digits.sdk.android:digits:1.11.1
|    |    +--- com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.7.0 (*)
|    |    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.12
|    |    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers-shim:0.0.3 FAILED   // <=== here it is ...
|    |    \--- com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit-mock:1.8.0
|    |         \--- com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.8.0 (*)
|    \--- com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:1.0.5
|         +--- com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.6.8 -> 1.7.0 (*)
|         +--- com.twitter:twitter-text:1.13.0
|         +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.12
|         \--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.38.1
```

So in your case, this `answers-shim` module is part of the `com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter` module transitive dependencies:  you need to check if there are some more recent versions of this module, as version `1.14.1` seems obsolete and depends on libraries that are no longer available on public repositories.